# How do you test render_remote_content receives the correct locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, rspec-rails

In a controller spec, I'm trying to test that a controller action calling render_remote_content renders the right partial with the correct.

Currently, I'm trying to do something like:

```
response.should render_template(partial: "path/to/_template", locals: {local_array: []})
```

This causes rspec to blow up in assert_template. I'd prefer to avoid stubbing render methods.

Anyone have any good ideas on how to accomplish this?

Rails 3.1
RSpec 2.7

Answer (score 0):

When you are checking for locals, it appears that there is a bug in the rspec code, and you have to **drop the underscore** in the partial name.

Specifically:

```
response.should render_template(partial: "path/to/template", locals: {local_array: []})
```

will work, but your example will not.

EDIT:

This issue is actually in assert_template, since render_template delegates to that. This issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8516